# Intel HAXM is not compatible with Hyper-V

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, hyper-v, haxm

I am using Visual Studio 2017 / Xamarin in windows 7 ultimate platform and using the Android Device Manager to run Android emulator in it.

When I try to run it says "Intel HAXM is not compatible with Hyper-V" and the Details are "You are attempting to accelerate the emulator using Intel’s HAXM, but you have Hyper-V enabled in your system settings. Disable Hyper-V by running: bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off in an elevated command prompt and restart your computer before trying again."

1. I have checked and in my system Hyper-V is not installed.
2. I also have run the bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off and after checking it is varified that the hypervisorlaunchtype is off now.
3. Also I have checked using system infomation and other tools and Hyper-V is not running.
4. Also I checked that HAXM is running by using the command "sc query intelhaxm" and shows it is running with State = 4

It looks like that Android Device Manager (Virtual Device) is checking some other parameter to detect if Hyper-V is running. Don't know if this is a registry setting or some other program is using intel VT (virtualization technology) and AVD is giving this message because of that. I have done lot of research on this, installed the latest HAXM etc. but no luck. Can someone help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh man, got the same one :( Will bookmark and answer if I figure this out...

Comment: Windows now supports Hyper-V for Android simulators. [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226559/making-hyper-v-and-intel-haxm-to-co-exist).

Answer (score 0):

De-select Hyper V from windows feature like this.

[Hyper v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxtJr.png)

Comment: Hi if you read my post carefully I have said I have NO hyper-v installed in my system. (see point 1). Thanks for the effort however.

Comment: Have you got VT-S enabled in bios?

Comment: I hope your PC has a intel processor? And try installing the haxm package from Android SDK manager once, if it is not installed already.